# Cannot write a question on macOS Mojave/Safari v13.0.3

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

What does not work? I cannot write a question.

- Description and tags are non-functional, description is faded out and tags do not provide dropdowns
- (title works fine)

Where does it now work? `macOS Mojave 10.14.6 / Safari v13.0.3`

Funny enough, I am writing this question on the same setup and it works. It really only happens on the **Stackoverflow for Teams**.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

*Bonus*: The orange button at the bottom right does not work, either.

[image]

I understand that v13.0.3 is quite old, but as I do not want to upgrade my MacBook with the successor OS for macOS Mojave, I am stuck with this version of Safari. I also get that the Stack Overflow for Teams is probably running a newer build and therefore fails here first.

I can work around and just use Firefox/Chrome which both work fine. It is not a problem for me, just wanted to report the bug :)

Comment: It looks like some javascript bits  are not loading properly and that stops all javascript processing. Are you or is your network blocking certain scripts? The network tab should show you that info.

Comment: Please update your browser. Safari v13.0.3 was released October 28, 2019... It's pretty old.

Comment: Looks like Stack Exchange only supports Safari 14 per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history) and [their version compatibility list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Comment: I don't now if anything has been done in between my initial post and now, but it works again and I can post questions again. So either it has been a bug on my machine (god knows what), or it is resolved.

Comment: It sounds like something in the JavaScript uses a lookbehind in a regular expression, maybe? IIRC, Safari doesn't support lookbehind yet